# Getting issues for redefinition of functions

Tags: c, function, redefinition

I'm trying to scan numbers into 2 2D arrays, and I keep on getting the error of redefinition.

The code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define N 3

  void getMatrix(double mat[N][N]);
 /*
 char getMenuOption();
 void getCoordinates(int*, int*);
  void sumMatrices(double mat1[][N], double mat2[][N]);
   void changeMatrix(double mat[][N]);
    void printMatrix(double mat[][N]);
*/
int main() {
double A[N][N], B[N][N];
/*
 char option;*/
getMatrix( A[N][N]);
getMatrix( B[N][N]);
/*

option = getMenuOption();*/

return 0;
 }
  void getMatrix(double A[N][N]){
int i;
for(i=0;i<=N;i++){
    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        scanf("%lf",&A[N][N]);
    }
    }
    return;

 }
    void getMatrix(double B[N][N]){
     int i;
for(i=0;i<=N;i++){
    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        scanf("%lf",&B[N][N]);
    }
    }
return;
  }
```

I guess the problem is that the same function is called twice, but im not so sure about it.
If anyone can help me point to the problem, it will be most welcome.

Comment: `problem is that the same function is called twice,`..heh? Isn't that the sole purpose of having them???

Comment: You implemented your function twice. There is no need to do that.

Comment: I dont know. i didnt say that this is the the error.

Comment: Zoli, can you offer a suggestion on how to write it please?

Comment: Your code formatting is a complete mess, so I won't read this question.

Comment: Why would you write `getMatrix( A[N][N]);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function is defined twice

First definition

```
  void getMatrix(double A[N][N]){
int i;
for(i=0;i<=N;i++){
    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        scanf("%lf",&A[N][N]);
    }
    }
    return;

 }
```

Second definition

```
    void getMatrix(double B[N][N]){
     int i;
for(i=0;i<=N;i++){
    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        scanf("%lf",&B[N][N]);
    }
    }
return;
  }
```

Take into account that these calls of the function are invalid

```
getMatrix( A[N][N]);
getMatrix( B[N][N]);
```

The arguments have type `double` instead of arrays or pointers.

You should remove one definition of the function and declare the function correctly.

If the compiler allows to use Variable Length Arrays then the functiuon should be declared like

```
void getMatrix(size_t n, double A[n][n]);
```

if Variable Length Arrays are not supported by the compiler then N must be a constant and the function indeed can be declared like

```
#define N SOME_VALUE
//...
void getMatrix( double A[N][N] );
```

and call the function like

in the first case

```
getMatrix( N, A );
getMatrix( N, B );
```

and in the second case

```
getMatrix( A );
getMatrix( B );
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to define a function **twice** (to call it twice or more). One function can be called multiple times, that's the reason of having functions in first place. Get rid of

```
void getMatrix(double B[N][N]){
     int i;
for(i=0;i<=N;i++){
    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        scanf("%lf",&B[N][N]);
    }
    }
return;
  }
```

Having said that, you should call the function like

```
getMatrix(A);
getMatrix(B);
```

To pass the array (*the decay to pointer, anyway*). The notation `A[N][N]` denotes a member of the array and for an array defined like

```
double A[N][N];
```

it's off-by-one, as array indexing in C starts from 0.